# Angular2 (Universal) y sesiones aplicación SPA

Tags: nodejs, angularjs-2.0, express, session, autenticación

Hola como están quería saber sobre como manejar las sesiones usando express+angular2 en una aplicación node , antes cuando no usaba angular2,y mis aplicaciones no eran precisamente SPA , era algo sencillo.

Me logeaba , el backend recibia el logeo del usuario , y este se autentificaba depependiendo de los datos , se generaba un token , de sesion , y se guardaba e, req.session los datos del token y el id del usuario , luego  cuando accedia a un endpoint , este endpoint pasaba por el middleware de passport para ver si estaba logeado y el token no habia expirado para darle acceso o redirigirle a otra página.

Ejemplo como lo hacia.

```
app.get('/paginaSecreta',isLogged,controller.PaginaSecreta)
//Si esta logeado o el token no ha experiado pasa ala pagina secreta,sino redirige.
```

A hora con angular2 , especificamente angular universal , veo que la cosa no deberia manejarla así , pues veo algunos ejemplos en el cual hacen una autentificacion,el servidor responde el token y almacen en el localStorage del cliente el token , luego con ese token con ayuda del AuthGuard de angular2 dan acceso a rutas ,dependiendo si esta logeado o no .

Surge mi duda , siempre he escuchado que la lógica de la sesión debe manejarse desde el backend , sin embargo con este enfoque lo tratan en el front end ,no he encontrado otro tipo de ejemplos , así que quisiera saber , si de esta forma en angular2 , sería escalable en el tiempo , a un paso en producción , obviamente no deberia usar el localStorage , sin embargo no se que otra alternativa hay o habrá para almacenar la sesion en el frontend usando un enfoque de SPA , me parece que también esta INDEXDB.

Aqui les paso un ejemplo como usan jwt para la autentificacion y manejar de cierta manera la sesion , junto el AuthGuard , que extiende de CanActivate del modulo @angular/router.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/TIPmK3?p=preview
```

Comment: No veo aquí un problema real de programación sino una confusión de conceptos que te recomiendo que aclares. Te dejo un enlace que puede ayudarte: http://www.adwe.es/general/colaboraciones/servicios-web-restful-con-http-parte-i-introduccion-y-bases-teoricas No puedo votar para cerrarla, pero esta pregunta tal como está redactada actualmente __debería__ cerrarse.